# Add content block in a page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, page-content, add

```
$listBusBlock = $listOfBuses->getLayout()->createBlock('Imonn\Bookings\Block\Buslist')->setTemplate('Imonn_Bookings::Busbooking/listOfBusses.phtml')->toHtml();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($listBusBlock);
```

in the above PHP code, I want to add $listBusBlock between the header and footer.

If I use `$this->getResponse()->setBody($listBusBlock);` the content is set to the entire body and the header and footer are gone.
what should I use instead of setBody so that the content can be added between the header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below snippets:

```
$listBusBlock = $listOfBuses->getLayout()->createBlock('Imonn\Bookings\Block\Buslist')->setTemplate('Imonn_Bookings::Busbooking/listOfBusses.phtml')->toHtml();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($listBusBlock);
```